Fix for the error WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser with Selenium
I have been getting this error for about an year now, when running Selenium webdriver/Java tests using Chrome driver. Is there a fix for this problem?  Following is the error:
unknown error: "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" while trying to initiate Chrome Browse
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Chrome failed to start: existed normally.
I am using Chrome latest version 128. I have tried WebdriverManager as well.
Let me know if anyone has a fix for this issue.
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.quit();

Expected: Chrome browser should be opened and should launch the website.
